# Simplify x from x |x|

Tags: calculus, absolute-value

I have that

$$ x |x| = -y, $$
Clearly the sign of x is determined by the sign of y. But then how to write what x is?What happens if y is discontinuous at 0?

Is it
$$ x = sgn(x) \sqrt{ |y|} ?$$
or doesn't it make any sense?there is something I probably don't understand.

silly example
$$ 5 |5| = - (-25)$$
x is positive when y negative and
$$ - 5 |-5| = - (25)$$
x is negative when y positive.

Comment: We can go at this by analyzing two cases (if we exclude $x=0$ as we just get the origin there): either $x>0$ or $x<0$. Try graphing it by plotting each individual case and seeing how it all comes together.

Comment: When $x\geq 0$, $x^2=-y$, and when $x<0$, $-x^2=-y$, i.e. $x^2=y$. So it looks like $x^2=-\text{sgn}(x)y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking this question in the case where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers rather than complex numbers.

It looks to me as if
$$
x = -\operatorname{sgn}(y) \sqrt{|y|}
$$
where you might have to do something when $y = 0$, depending on the definition of "sgn".

In other words, your conjectured answer was almost correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are four solutions:

$x = \pm \sqrt{y}$ and $\pm i \sqrt{y}$.

Comment: But some of those are spurious: if $y=+4$ then $x=+2$ is not a solution

Comment: thanks for the answer, I should have mentioned x and y are real.

Answer (score 1):

$y = \begin{cases}x^2 & x\le 0\\-x^2 & x>0 \end{cases}$

and to invert this.

$x = \begin{cases} \sqrt {-y} & y\le 0\\ -\sqrt{y} & y> 0\end {cases}$

or $x = -\text{sgn}(y)\sqrt{|y|}$

Comment: I guess(typo) in the first is $$x >0.$$
Shouldn't be minus sign in the end as in the other comment? The signs were from beginning what was confusing to me.